# Convert a table with different relational values to excel columns

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, code-first

I have these tables:

**Category**

```
CategoryId
CategoryTitle
...
ICollection<Article> Articles
```

Each category can have several articles:

**Article**

```
ArticleId
ArticleTitle  
NumberOfComment
NumberOfView
...
ICollection<ArticleReview> Reviews
```

And each article has several reviews by some user:

**ArticleReview**

```
ArticleReviewId 
ReviewPoint
ArticleId
ReviewerId
```

i am trying to export excel report using [EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus/) package
Here is my `ExcelExport` class :

```
public class excelExport 
{
    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }

    public int NumberOfComment { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfReviews { get; set; }
    public List<ResearchReviewReport> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleReviewReport
{
    public string Reviewer { get; set; }
    public int ReviewPoint { get; set; }
}
```

**Note**: Since the number of reviews for an article is different, I use *one-to-many* relationship, but in final result all of them should be flatten in single row. Now I create new class that does not belong to database and I pass this class to `ExcelPackage` class to generate *xlsx* as output :

**ExcelExport**

```
ArticleTitle 
Reviewer1Point
Reviewer2Point
............
ReviewerNPoint
ReviewersAvaragePoint
NumberOfComment
NumberOfView
```

How can I populate the `ExcelExport` class by using another 3 classes?

---

**Edit**
here is my expected excel output
[image: Excel final Export]

One of my problems is Reviewer Point column is dynamically changed,
for one article may be there 3 column (like upper image) but in another may be 4 or 5 Reviewer Point.
**Edit2**
i forgot to say there is some question for each article and Reviewer answer to each question ,so if we have 3 question and there is 2 Reviewer,article hase 6 ArticleReview and i should get average of ArticleReview for each Reviewer  and put it in single cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep things simple, I assume you are using the following simplified models and will describe the solution. You can easily adapt it to your models:

```
public class Article
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public List<Review> Reviews { get; set; }
}
public class Review
{
    public int Points { get; set; }
}
```

Now we are going to generate the following output, having dynamic number of reviewer columns, depending to the input data:

[image]

**Solution**

It's enough to create a function to convert a `List<Article>` to a `DataTable`. To create such `DataTable`, for each property of the `Article`, add a new column. Then find the maximum count of `Reviews` list and add that number of columns. Then in a loop, for each `Article` including its `Review` list, create an array of objects and add to the `DataTable`. Obviously you also can perform calculation on fields.

Here is the function:

```
public DataTable GetData(List<Article> list)
{
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    var max = list.Max(x => x.Reviews.Count());
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        dt.Columns.Add($"Reviewer {i + 1} Points", typeof(int));
    foreach (var item in list)
        dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.Title, item.Date }.Concat(
            item.Reviews.Select(x => x.Points).Cast<object>()).ToArray());
    return dt;
}
```

**Test Data**

Here is my test data:

```
var list = new List<Article>
{
    new Article(){
        Title = "Article 1", Date = new DateTime(2018,1,1),
        Reviews = new List<Review> {
            new Review(){Points=10},
        },
    },
    new Article(){
        Title = "Article 2", Date = new DateTime(2018,1,2),
        Reviews = new List<Review> {
            new Review(){Points=10}, new Review(){Points=9}, new Review(){Points=8},
        },
    },
    new Article(){
        Title = "Article 3", Date = new DateTime(2018,1,3),
        Reviews = new List<Review> {
            new Review(){Points=9},
        },
    },
};
```

Comment: Updated the method to use `Concat` to concatenate arrays.

Comment: why not use TypeDescriptor.GetProperties to add Columns?

Comment: We can use. It's just an example as a start point. Just keep in mine, if you use `TypeDescriptor.GetProperties` you need to exclude the list property.

Comment: i use this article for excel exporting,https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/export-to-excel-in-asp-net-mvc/ this create column title separately and pass it to  ExportExcel method

Comment: I see. Now you have the `DataTable` (solved the biggest problem, handling the variable number of items in the list and making a flat result.) The next step (which is the easiest part) is exporting `DataTable` to excel.

Comment: The class which you shared has a `ExportExcel` method which accepts data table as input.

Comment: @AminM Does it add any complexity to the `GetData` method? I'd say no. It's just some calculation. For example in this piece of code `dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { item.Title, item.Date }.Concat(
            item.Reviews.Select(x => CALCULATION).Cast<object>()).ToArray());` replace `CALCULATION` with whatever calculation which you need. At that point, you have access to `item` which is an article with all of its properties.

Comment: there is another problem,what if one post have 4 review another have 5 and other have 2??? it change position of averages

Comment: If you read the example carefully, I've defined the number of columns using `var max = list.Max(x => x.Reviews.Count());` it means the number of `Reviews` is not important for us and we can handle any number. Also in the sample data which I provided as part of the answer, one of the rows have 3 reviews and the other rows have one review. I couldn't see any problem in the approach.

Comment: i create two seperate table one for reviewer added to review article and one to hold review poinst,i use User table to generate header but problem is some user doesn't review and review point of other user added to this user row when i want to get export

Comment: I think it's more about playing with business logic than trying to solve a technical problem. Anyway, if you can reproduce the problem using a [MCVE] and describe the technical problem with which you are facing, feel free to ask a new question and I as well as other community members will take a look at the question.

Comment: I usually advise against doing this, because the question has already an answer and both question and answer are long enough and it will makes the Q/A less useful for future readers.

Comment: i will thanks to you if you answer my new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58545159/

Comment: I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have following model:

```
public class Category
{
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }
}

public class Article
{
    public long ArticleId { get; set; }
    public long CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfComment { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfView { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ArticleReview> Reviews { get; set; }
}
public class ArticleReview
{
    public long ArticleReviewId { get; set; }
    public long ArticleId { get; set; }
    public string ReviewerId { get; set; }
    public int ReviewPoint { get; set; }
    public virtual Article Article { get; set; }
}
public class ExcelExport
{
    public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfComment { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfReviews { get; set; }
    public List<ArticleReviewReport> Reviews { get; set; }
}

public class ArticleReviewReport
{
    public string Reviewer { get; set; }
    public int ReviewPoint { get; set; }
}
```

Eventually you are going to have List of `ExcelExport` and the query should look like (`_context` is an instance of your Entity DbContext):

```
public List<ExcelExport> GetExcelExports()
{
    return _context.Articles.Select(a => new ExcelExport
    {
        ArticleTitle = a.ArticleTitle,
        NumberOfComment = a.NumberOfComment,
        NumberOfReviews = a.NumberOfView,
        Reviews = a.Reviews.Select(r => new ArticleReviewReport
        {
            Reviewer = r.ReviewerId,
            ReviewPoint = r.ReviewPoint
        }).ToList()
    }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: how ArticleReviewReport flat in single row for each Articles??also each table are separate

Comment: this is completely worng, i want show each Review on single coulmn but it return list of it !

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for. From what I can decipher the goal is to “flatten” the data from the given “classes”. I am going to forgo the export to Excel as this appears to be a different problem. The “Classes” exist, I am guessing a method that returned a `DataTable` or any “collection” type you desire. I am guessing this would make things easier when exporting to Excel.

In the `Catergory` class, it has a “collection” of `Article’s`. Each `Article` represents a “row” in the collection (Excel spreadsheet). Each `Article` has a “collection” of `ArticleReviews` called `Reviews`. As you stated…

> One of my problems is Reviewer Point column is dynamically changed,
>   for one article may be there 3 column (like upper image) but in
>   another may be 4 or 5 Reviewer Point.

This sounds like there could be many reviewers for each `Article` in addition, not all reviewers will necessarily “review” all articles. Given this and the requirement to “flatten” this data would mean creating a column for “each” reviewer. In addition, I assume that only reviewers who reviewed one of the articles are listed, otherwise, it would be simple to create a column for each reviewer. I am guessing the goal is to only have columns where the reviewer “reviewed” at least one (1) article.

With that said, I am guessing the first problem is figuring out “how many” columns do we need for the reviewers and “what” are those reviewers’ names are. We will need some way to identify “which” column belongs to which reviewer. I am using the `Reviewer` name to identify the correct column. So how do we find the reviewers…

It is convenient, that the `Category` class has a list of `Artlicle`s. If a method was created that went through each article and then go through each review of the article and gather all the reviewers and ignore duplicates… this should give us the list of “reviewers” we need to add columns for. If the method retuned a list of `Reviewer` we could use this to determine not only how many columns we need but also what the names of those columns should be.

One possible issue in this is that the column order may be unpredictable. Depending on which article is first, is going to determine the order of the columns. Therefore, I recommend some “sorting” of the columns to maintain some order.

I added a class `Reviewer` that should help in the sorting and comparing column names. It is a simple `Reviewer` class like below. Note the `compareTo` method that is used by the sort. It sorts by the reviewers ID. This will keep the same column order.

```
public class Reviewer : IComparable<Reviewer> {

  public int ReviewerID { get; set; }
  public string ReviewerName { get; set; }

  public Reviewer() {
  }

  public Reviewer(int reviewerID, string reviewerName) {
    ReviewerID = reviewerID;
    ReviewerName = reviewerName;
  }

  public override string ToString() {
    return "ReviewerID: " + ReviewerID.ToString();
  }

  public override bool Equals(object obj) {
    return this.ReviewerName.Equals(((Reviewer)obj).ReviewerName);
  }

  public override int GetHashCode() {
    return ReviewerName.GetHashCode();
  }

  public int CompareTo(Reviewer other) {
    return this.ReviewerID.CompareTo(other.ReviewerID);
  }
}
```

This is going to affect the `ArticleReview` class and some changes are needed there. Some variables appear unnecessary, and only the needed variables are shown. The main change is the `Reviewer` object from above to define the reviewer.

```
public class ArticleReview {

  public long ArticleId { get; set; }
  public Reviewer TheReviewer { get; set; }
  public int ReviewPoint { get; set; }

  public ArticleReview() {
  }

  public ArticleReview (long articleId, Reviewer reviewerId, int reviewPoint) {
    ArticleId = articleId;
    TheReviewer = reviewerId;
    ReviewPoint = reviewPoint;
  }
}
```

Next is the `Article` class. It holds all the reviews for that article. It appears there is a column called “Average point”. This looks like a “computed” value from the reviews. Therefore, I am guessing it would be convenient for the `Article` class to “compute” this value for us. It has all the reviews… all that is needed is to add up all the points and divide by the number of reviews. This method is added to the `Article` class.

```
public class Article {
  public long ArticleId { get; set; }
  public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfComment { get; set; }
  public int NumberOfView { get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<ArticleReview> Reviews { get; set; }

  public Article() {
  }

  public Article(long articleId, string articleTitle, int numberOfComment, int numberOfView, ICollection<ArticleReview> reviews) {
    ArticleId = articleId;
    ArticleTitle = articleTitle;
    NumberOfComment = numberOfComment;
    NumberOfView = numberOfView;
    Reviews = reviews;
  }

  public decimal GetAverage() {
    if (Reviews.Count <= 0)
      return 0;
    decimal divisor = Reviews.Count;
    int totPoints = 0;
    foreach (ArticleReview review in Reviews) {
      totPoints += review.ReviewPoint;
    }
    return totPoints / divisor;
  }
}
```

Lastly the `Category` class holds all the `Article`s. This class is where we need to do all the column stuff described earlier. The first part is getting a `List<Reviewer>` without duplicates. This will require looping through all the articles and then looping through all the reviews in each article. In this process we can examine the “reviewers” and create a non-duplicated list of all the users. The code creates a new empty `List<Reviewer>` then loops through each article, the loops through each review. A check is made to see if the “reviewer” is already in the list, if not, then add them, otherwise ignore the duplicate “reviewer.” The list is sorted to maintain column order then it is returned.

I am guessing this list could be used in many ways to solve the “columns” conundrum. In this example, another method is added to the `Category` class. The `GetDataTable` method returns a `DataTable` from the data in the articles. To start the first four columns are added to the table, “Title” “#ofView”, “#ofComment” and “Average point.” Next a loop through all the reviewers to add the reviewer columns. The reviewer name is used as the column name. This is how we identify which column belongs to which reviewer when adding the data.

Finally, a loop through each `Article` to add the data. Each article creates a new row. The first three columns in the row can be set… Title, view, comment and Average. Next, we loop through all the reviews. For each review `targetName` is set to the reviewer’s name, then a loop through each column until it finds the column name that matches the reviewers name. When found we know that this is the column the data belongs in. Add the value and break out of the columns loop and get the next review.

```
public class Category {
  public long CategoryId { get; set; }
  public string CategoryTitle { get; set; }
  //...
  public virtual ICollection<Article> Articles { get; set; }

  public Category() {
  }

  public Category(long categoryId, string categoryTitle, ICollection<Article> articles) {
    CategoryId = categoryId;
    CategoryTitle = categoryTitle;
    Articles = articles;
  }

  public DataTable GetDataTable() {
    List<Reviewer> allReviewers = GetNumberOfReviewers();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Title", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("#ofView", typeof(long));
    dt.Columns.Add("#ofComment", typeof(long));
    dt.Columns.Add("Average point", typeof(decimal));
    foreach (Reviewer reviewer in allReviewers) {
      dt.Columns.Add(reviewer.ReviewerName, typeof(long));
    }
    foreach (Article article in Articles) {
      DataRow newRow = dt.NewRow();
      newRow["Title"] = article.ArticleTitle;
      newRow["#ofView"] = article.NumberOfView;
      newRow["#ofComment"] = article.NumberOfComment;
      newRow["Average point"] = article.GetAverage();
      foreach (ArticleReview review in article.Reviews) {
        string targetName = review.TheReviewer.ReviewerName;
        for (int i = 4; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++) {
          if (targetName == dt.Columns[i].ColumnName) {
            newRow[review.TheReviewer.ReviewerName] = review.ReviewPoint;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      dt.Rows.Add(newRow);
    }
    return dt;
  }

  private List<Reviewer> GetNumberOfReviewers() {
    // we need a list of all the different reviewers
    List<Reviewer> reviewers = new List<Reviewer>();
    foreach (Article article in Articles) {
      foreach (ArticleReview review in article.Reviews) {
        if (!reviewers.Contains(review.TheReviewer)) {
          reviewers.Add(review.TheReviewer);
        }
      }
    }
    reviewers.Sort();
    return reviewers; 
  }
}
```

Putting this all together, the code below creates some data to demonstrate. Then, the `DataTable` is used as a `DataSource` to a `DataGridView`. I hope this helps.

```
DataTable dt;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Category cat = new Category();
  cat.CategoryId = 1;
  cat.CategoryTitle = "Category 1";
  cat.Articles = GetArticles();
  dt = cat.GetDataTable();
  dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
}

private List<Article> GetArticles() {
  List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();
  Article art = new Article(1, "Article 1 Title", 10, 1200, GetReviews(1));
  articles.Add(art);
  art = new Article(2, "Article 2 Title", 32, 578, GetReviews(2));
  articles.Add(art);
  art = new Article(3, "Article 3 Title", 15, 132, GetReviews(3));
  articles.Add(art);
  art = new Article(4, "Article 4 Title", 13, 133, GetReviews(4));
  articles.Add(art);
  art = new Article(5, "Article 5 Title", 55, 555, GetReviews(5));
  articles.Add(art);
  art = new Article(6, "Article 6 Title", 0, 0, GetReviews(6));
  articles.Add(art);
  return articles;
}

private ICollection<ArticleReview> GetReviews(int reviewId) {
  ICollection<ArticleReview> reviews = new List<ArticleReview>();
  ArticleReview ar;
  Reviewer Reviewer1 = new Reviewer(1, "Reviewer 1");
  Reviewer Reviewer2 = new Reviewer(2, "Reviewer 2");
  Reviewer Reviewer3 = new Reviewer(3, "Reviewer 3");
  Reviewer Reviewer4 = new Reviewer(4, "Reviewer 4");
  Reviewer Reviewer5 = new Reviewer(5, "Reviewer 5");
  Reviewer Reviewer6 = new Reviewer(6, "Reviewer 6");

  switch (reviewId) {
    case 1:
      ar = new ArticleReview(1, Reviewer1, 15);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(1, Reviewer2, 35);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(1, Reviewer3, 80);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(1, Reviewer5, 55);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(1, Reviewer6, 666);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      break;
    case 2:
      ar = new ArticleReview(2, Reviewer1, 50);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(2, Reviewer2, 60);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(2, Reviewer3, 40);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      break;
    case 3:
      ar = new ArticleReview(3, Reviewer1, 60);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(3, Reviewer2, 60);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(3, Reviewer3, 80);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      break;
    case 4:
      ar = new ArticleReview(4, Reviewer1, 30);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(4, Reviewer2, 70);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      ar = new ArticleReview(4, Reviewer3, 70);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      break;
    case 5:
      ar = new ArticleReview(5, Reviewer3, 44);
      reviews.Add(ar);
      break;
    case 6:
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return reviews;
}
```

Using EPPlus, below is one way to use the `DataTable` above and export the `DataTable` to an Excel worksheet.

```
private void btn_ExportToExcel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  using (var p = new ExcelPackage()) {
    var ws = p.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("MySheet");
    ws.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dt, true);
    p.SaveAs(new FileInfo(@"D:\Test\ExcelFiles\EpplusExport.xlsx"));
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> How can I populate the excelExport class used another 3 classes?

Based on described relationships, You can enumerate each property inside `ExcelExport` class like below :

`NumberOfComment` is equal to `article.NumberOfComment` for each article entry! **Unless** you employ another table named `ArticleComment` and take advantage of *navigation property* inside `Article` class (using `public virtual ICollection<ArticleComment> Comments { get; set;}`), Then count the number of comments with `article.Comments.Count()`.

`NumberOfReviews` is equal to `article.Reviews.Count()` for each article entry.

`Reviews` for each article can be some thing like the following:

```
article.Reviews.Select(s => new ArticleReviewReport { 
       Reviewer = r.ReviewerId, // user id
       ReviewPoint = r.ReviewPoint
});
```

It seems you must also add another property to your `ExcelExport` class to show `ReviewersAvaragePoint` and enumerate that like this:

```
var reviewPoints = article.Reviews.Select(s => s.ReviewPoint);
ReviewersAvaragePoint = reviewPoints.Sum()/reviewPoints.Count();
```

**Edit based on OP's edit**

By employing a `List` of `ArticleReviewReport` (e.g. `List<ArticleReviewReport> Reviews`) you have a flexible array (dynamic columns) to present in corresponding format. **The missing part** is making dynamic columns based on Distinct `ReviewerId` extracted from the `ArticleReview` table. Something like the following for entire articles:

```
var allReviewers = db.articleReviews/*condition*/.Select(s => s.ReviewerId).Distinct();
```

Now you can assign each `ArticleReviewReport` to the corresponding column. Using a `List<Dictionary<string, string>>` would be a good *data type* for `Reviews` member.

Answer (score 0):

```
public IEnumarable<ExcelExport> GetExcelExports()
{
    return _context.Articles.Select(a => new ExcelExport
    {
       ArticleTitle = a.ArticleTitle,
       NumberOfComment = a.NumberOfComment,
       NumberOfReviews = a.NumberOfView,
       Reviewer1Point = a.Reviews.Any(e => e.ReviewerId = 1) ? a.Reviews.Where(e => e.ReviewerId = 1).Sum(e => e.ReviewPoint) : 0,
       Reviewer2Point = a.Reviews.Any(e => e.ReviewerId = 2) ? a.Reviews.Where(e => e.ReviewerId = 2).Sum(e => e.ReviewPoint) : 0,
       ....
       ReviewerNPoint = a.Reviews.Any(e => e.ReviewerId = N) ? a.Reviews.Where(e => e.ReviewerId = N).Sum(e => e.ReviewPoint) : 0
     });
}
```

You also have to .Include(e => e.Reviews) if you use lazy loading.