# Convert many table to excel columns

Tags: excel, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I create web app for article review.

I have table named Article and each `Article` have some `ArticleReview`:

**Article**

```
ArticleId
ArticleTitle  
NumberOfComment
NumberOfView
...
ICollection<ArticleReview> Reviews
```

Admin can add many user (I call them JueryUser) and send article to them for review, I use table named ArticlePoint for adding/removing User's that can review each Article:

**ArticlePoint**

```
public int ArticlePointId { get; set; }
public DateTime CreateOn { get; set; }
public string Id { get; set; }      // Id of User that review Article
public ApplicationUser JuryUser { get; set; }
public string UserId { get; set; } // Id of User that write Article
public int ArticleId { get; set; }
public string JuryReview { get; set; }
```

When Jury user review article he/she gave article some point, this points is based on question's that provided by Admin, this review's are stored in `ArticleReview` table.

**ArticleReview**

```
ArticleReviewId 
ReviewPoint
ArticleId
ReviewerId
```

As I said in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53692304/convert-a-table-with-different-relational-values-to-excel-columns/53804622) I want to get excel export from summery of point that gave to articles by each juery.

I use this below code to generate my excel file:

```
public static class ExcelExportHelper
    {
        public static string ExcelContentType => "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";

        public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> data)
        {
            PropertyDescriptorCollection properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            for (int i = 0; i < properties.Count; i++)
            {
                PropertyDescriptor property = properties[i];
                dataTable.Columns.Add(property.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(property.PropertyType) ?? property.PropertyType);
            }

            object[] values = new object[properties.Count];
            foreach (T item in data)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
                {
                    values[i] = properties[i].GetValue(item);
                }

                dataTable.Rows.Add(values);
            }
            return dataTable;
        }

        public static byte[] ExportExcel(DataTable dataTable, string heading = "", bool showSrNo = false, params string[] columnsToTake)
        {
            byte[] result = null;
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage())
            {
                ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add(String.Format("{0} Data", heading));
                workSheet.View.RightToLeft = true;
                int startRowFrom = String.IsNullOrEmpty(heading) ? 1 : 3;

                if (showSrNo)
                {
                    DataColumn dataColumn = dataTable.Columns.Add("#", typeof(int));
                    dataColumn.SetOrdinal(0);
                    int index = 1;
                    foreach (DataRow item in dataTable.Rows)
                    {
                        item[0] = index;
                        index++;
                    }
                }

                // add the content into the Excel file  
                workSheet.Cells["A" + startRowFrom].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);
                // format header - bold, yellow on black  
                using (ExcelRange r = workSheet.Cells[startRowFrom, 1, startRowFrom, dataTable.Columns.Count])
                {
                    r.Style.Font.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.White);
                    r.Style.Font.Bold = true;
                    r.Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                    r.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#1fb5ad"));
                }

                // format cells - add borders  
                using (ExcelRange r = workSheet.Cells[startRowFrom + 1, 1, startRowFrom + dataTable.Rows.Count, dataTable.Columns.Count])
                {
                    r.Style.Border.Top.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    r.Style.Border.Bottom.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    r.Style.Border.Left.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;
                    r.Style.Border.Right.Style = ExcelBorderStyle.Thin;

                    r.Style.Border.Top.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                    r.Style.Border.Bottom.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                    r.Style.Border.Left.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                    r.Style.Border.Right.Color.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
                }

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(heading))
                {
                    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value = heading;
                    workSheet.Cells["A1"].Style.Font.Size = 20;

                    workSheet.InsertColumn(1, 1);
                    workSheet.InsertRow(1, 1);
                    workSheet.Column(1).Width = 5;
                }

                result = package.GetAsByteArray();
            }

            return result;
        }

        public static byte[] ExportExcel<T>(List<T> data, string Heading = "", bool showSlno = false, params string[] ColumnsToTake)
        {
            return ExportExcel(ListToDataTable<T>(data), Heading, showSlno, ColumnsToTake);
        }
    }
```

and use this code in my action method:

```
  public ActionResult ExportToExcel()
        {
            byte[] filecontent;
            try
            {

                var juryLists = from user in db.Users
                                where user.Roles.Any(r => r.RoleId == "IdOfRole")
                                select user;

                var articles = db.Articles.Include(r=>r.ArticleReview).Where(r2=>r2.ArticleReviews.Any()).ToList();

                List<string> cmnList = new List<string>();
                cmnList.Add("Article Title");
                cmnList.Add("Point Avarage");
                var juryListNames = juryLists.OrderBy(x=>x.Id).Select(x => "JuryPoints : " + x.FullName).ToList();
                cmnList.AddRange(juryListNames);
                string[] columns = cmnList.ToArray();

                var heading = $"Results";

                var dt = new DataTable();
                foreach (var column in columns)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(column, typeof(string));
                }

                foreach (var item in articles)
                {
                    var _obj = new object[] { item.ArticleTitle, item.ArticleReviews.OrderBy(x=>x.JuryUserId).Select(x=>x.ArticlePoint).Average() }.Concat(
                        item.ArticleReviews.OrderBy(x => x.JuryUserId).GroupBy(x => x.JuryUserId).Select(x => x.Average(y => y.ReviewPoint))
                            .Cast<object>()).ToArray();
                    dt.Rows.Add(_obj);
                }
                filecontent = ExcelExportHelper.ExportExcel(dt, heading, true, columns);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Details",new {id= id });
            }


            return File(filecontent, ExcelExportHelper.ExcelContentType, "Results.xlsx");
        }
```

My Problem:
I create header for my excel but problem is some jury user wont gave point to article yet and when I generate excel, point of another jury placed in column of another one.
ex: one article sent to 5 jury jury 1,2 and 5 give point to article but after export point of 5th jury place in 3th jury column 
how can I resolve this?

Comment: @Yared admin declare some question(say 5) and then we have 3 jury that review article,when admin send article to juery,based on number of questions i create on ArticleReview for jury,in my example 15 ArticleReview  created(ech jury have 5,if admin send 2 article to 3 jury,ArticleReview  become 30

Comment: I am confused with your models. I have created a repository in github here: https://github.com/YaredDejene/excelexport. Can you please help on the models in the repository? Once I have a clear model relationship, i will try to solve the issue.

Comment: @Yared sorry i don't understand where you confused? Of course my database has bad design.as i said before i needed a mechanism for add/remove jury form article whenever i want so i create articlePoint to store 'Which jury review specific article' and admin can remove jury from specific article whenever he want,the ArticlePoint field inside ArticleReview hold point of each question that jury gave to article,as i say before based of number of question that admin declare,each article have several ArticleReview and i get avarage of ArticleReview.ArticlePoint

Comment: Okay, how about `ArticleReview.ReviewPoint`? Is this the maximum point for a given review? And Where do you store the questions ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201536/discussion-between-yared-and-aminm).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to include those reviews that are not yet added or expected to be filled by the reviewer, you can use a simple `left outer join` between the jury list and calculated averages for each of the juries who gave reviews. If reviews are missing for a jury, the `left outer join` will result an empty value average side. Therefore, a simple placeholder like a hyphen,an empty string, or a zero is populated. To achieve all these, you need to change the second `for loop` in the action method as below:

```
foreach (var item in articles)
{
    //Prepare list of averages for this article by grouping by individual jury
    //Resulting listcontains objects with two attributes, i.e. JuryUserId and Avg
    //JuryUserId is needed here for later join with user(jury) list
    var averages = item.ArticleReviews.GroupBy(x => x.JuryUserId).Select(x => new { JuryUserId = x.Key, Avg = x.Average(y => y.ReviewPoint) });

    //Left outer join of juries with list of averages  
    //If reviews are not found or yet to be added, a hyphen will be populated as a placeholder 
    var joinedAvg = from jury in juryLists
                join avg in averages on jury.Id equals avg.JuryUserId into j
                from result in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
                orderby jury.Id
                select (result?.Avg.ToString() ?? "-"); //Use any placeholder here

    var _obj = new object[] { item.ArticleTitle, item.ArticleReviews.Select(x => x.ReviewPoint).Average() }.Concat(joinedAvg.Cast<object>()).ToArray();

    dt.Rows.Add(_obj);

}
```